# Sympy module is Running very Slow

Tags: python, performance, geometry, sympy

Given a list of lengths and a point (x,y), I would like to find if a circle centered around (a,b) with radius 25 intersects any lines. The lines are all centered around the point (x,y), has a length of the corresponding index in the list of lengths, and all adjacent lines have the same "angle" (all the lines are equally spaced in terms of angles)

I have tried using Sympy, but unfortunately, it is very slow. Before, my game was running at 50-60 fps, but now it runs at 0.3-0.5 fps. Unfortunately, I do not know what is causing all the lag, so I will show the whole function:

```py
# the point where the lines are centered around is represented by pl.x,pl.y
#sympy is imported as sym
def shotcheck(self,lines):
        x,y = self.x,self.y #x and y represent the center of the circle
        c = sym.Circle(sym.Point(x,y,evaluate=False),25)
        diff = 2*math.pi/len(lines)
        direction = math.acos((x-pl.x)/hypot((pl.x-x),(pl.y-y)))
        if y < pl.y:
            direction = 2*math.pi-direction
        dfind = direction -0.005
        lowline,highline = math.floor(dfind/diff),math.ceil(dfind/diff)
        lline = sym.Segment(sym.Point(pl.x,pl.y,evaluate=False),sym.Point(pl.x+lines[lowline]*math.cos(a*lowline+0.005),pl.y+lines[lowline]*math.sin(a*lowline+0.005),evaluate=False))
        hline = sym.Segment(sym.Point(pl.x,pl.y,evaluate=False),sym.Point(pl.x+lines[highline]*math.cos(a*highline+0.005),pl.y+lines[highline]*math.sin(a*highline+0.005),evaluate=False))
        if len(sym.intersection(c,lline)) == 0 and len(sym.intersection(c,hline)) == 0:
            return False
        else:
            return True #Returns True if intersecting
```

I expected this to run decently fast, but it brings down the fps completely.
What can I do to fix this?
Edit: I have found that the lag is caused by sym.intersection. How do I make it faster?

Comment: Please post a drawing of the problem, your description is very confusing.

Comment: SymPy is a symbolic library. You should use it to find equations that you then implement in faster numeric code rather than calling it in each loop of a simulation